# DHCP server of Class B Network

Tags: wireless-access-point, dhcp-server

As far as I know, normally a DHCP server of Class C Network, which is able to serve for 256 clients in total only.

Do you guys have any idea about DHCP server of Class B Network? Customer asked if it is possible to do Class B Network to serve for 256*2 clients in one Acess Point.

Can I set the DHCP configuration as follows?
 lan interface netmask to 255.255.0.0, then set the DHCP Limit to 512.

What is the advantages of using Class B Network?

Comment: Classes are a rather old concept. There is no reason why a DHCP server would be limited to a Class C network and even if it is, it should be possible to setup multiple zones. What is the actual software/hardware you're using?

Comment: Classes stopped mattering many, many years ago. Just forget about them unless you have to pass some certification exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class B network is 65536 (2^16) addresses, not just 512.

Serving out more addresses from a DHCP server requires the DHCP server to use more memory. This is fine on a PC, but harder for a low-cost consumer embedded home gateway router product, where memory may be limited.

Serving out more DHCP addresses doesn't help get more devices on the internet unless you adjust your NAT gateway to also support the new, larger subnet. Again, this takes more memory.

Another issue to be aware of is how many TCP connections (or UDP flows) you can support per NAT public IP address. TCP and UDP each support only 65536 ports per IP address. If you're sharing that pool of ports among 256 or fewer clients, each client can have 256 or more simultaneous connections, which is usually plenty. But if you're sharing that pool among a true Class B's worth of hosts (65536 hosts) each can only average one connection, which isn't enough. Loading a single web page can require dozens of connections.

To support enough connections for 65536 clients, you need your NAT to support multiple public IP addresses. This is not a common feature on consumer home gateway router products. It's a feature of enterprise-class routers and firewalls.